# Can anyone tell me how to write application.path in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

i want to use current folder as a "source folder". so as in vb we write **application.path**
so how it will be in batch programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.path does not give you 'current path' - it returns where the app executes from.

In batch, equivalent would be `%~f0`(full path with command name) or `%~dp0` (path only).

Answer (score 0):

%CD% will get the current directory.

Comment: :currently i am using following code for copying file xcopy D:\temp\path.txt D:\temp\test\ /i /q /y    so how i use %CD% in it.